# Organising white house tour as never-resided US citizen

Tags: usa, us-citizens

US citizens who want to visit the White House are supposed to book a tour through their Representative or Senator. US citizens who reside abroad usually use their last state of residence. Which Representative or Senator should citizens not living in the US and who have never lived in the US apply to, and what address should they use?

In addition, is it possible to be in the same party as a non-citizen? if it helps, the other person is an EU citizen of which I am also a citizen.

Comment: Do you have relatives currently in the US? Or perhaps use the last state of residence of your parents?

Comment: Last state of residenc eof my parents would be RI. I'm currently in the US, no relatives.